# Show that if $M$ is closed ,then $(M^\perp)^\perp=M$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

let $M$ be a subspace of a normed space $X$ and $N$ a subspace of its dual $X^{*}$. we define

$M^\perp=\{f\in X^{*}:f(x)=0,\forall x\in M\}$ and

$N^\perp=\{x\in X:f(x)=0,\forall f\in N\}$

Show that if $M$ is cloesd ,then $(M^\perp)^\perp=M$

i think $M\subset(M^\perp)^\perp$ is easy. but how to do other way. any hint

Comment: Hahn-Banach helps.

Comment: @ Danial Fischer please a bit more elaborate

Comment: You want to show that $(M^{\perp})^{\perp} \subset M$. So for $x \notin M$ you want to find an $f\in M^{\perp}$ with $f(x) \neq 0$.

Comment: let $x_0\in N^\perp$ and $x_0 \notin M$, where $N=M^\perp$. then there exist a $f_0 \in X^{*}$ such that $f_0(x_0)\neq0$ and $f_0(x)=0 \ \forall x\in M$.thus $f_0\in M^\perp$.

But then $x_0\in N^\perp$ imply $f(x_0)=0 \forall f\in M^\perp$. in particular $f_0(x_0)=0$. which is contradiction to above .

is it correct

Comment: @DanielFischer IS IT WRIGHT

Comment: Yes, but you're muddying the waters. It's much clearer if you drop the mentions of $N^{\perp}$. Just "Let $x_0 \notin M$. Then there exists an $f_0 \in X^{\ast}$ such that $f_0(x_0) \neq 0$ and $f_0(x) = 0$ for all $x\in M$. Thus $f_0 \in M^{\perp}$." And hence $x_0 \notin (M^{\perp})^{\perp}$. And it would be good to say why there is such an $f_0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer ya thanks.